# How to access and modify a variable in the main Python script from an imported module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

When I want to change the value of a variable called **[X]** in my main script called **[main.py]** from inside one of the modules connected to my main script called **[module_1.py]**.
I need to import  my main script called**[main.py]** in the module **[module_1.py]** so that I can access the values inside the main script **[main.py]** and I can change the value of the variable **[X]**.
but when the **main script [main.py]** Entered in the module **[module_1.py]**, Python reads all the code of the main script **[main.py]** as a **module**,And when I set the value of the variable named **[X]** inside the main script **[main.py]** in the form of `main.x = 12` from the module **[module_1.py]**, it actually goes to the module **[main]** and the variable **[X]** I connect inside it and set its value to 12 and I cannot connect to the **main script [main.py]** and the variable **[X]** inside it.

I have a main Python script named **main.py** and I also have a Python module named **module_1.py**, which I imported into my main script, **main.py**, and then I imported my main script into the module **module_1.py** because I needed to change the value of a variable in the main **script****main.py** from inside the module **module_1.py**, and in order not to have the problem of circular repetition, I imported **main.py** into a function called **pp():** and under it main. I put **x = 12** so that when this function is executed, the value of the **x** variable in my main **script** changes, but this does not happen, and because when I import **main.py** in **module_1.py**, my main script itself is not imported. And in fact, it is a module that is imported, and my change is applied by the function **pp():** on **main.x** to the value of the variable **x** in the **main.py** module, and the value of the variable **x** in my main script, i.e. **main.py**, does not change .

How can I change the value of variable **X** inside my **main script** from **module_1.py**, which is imported into my **main** **script** file **main.py**, when `ــnameــ = ــmainــ`, not the value of variable **X** inside **module** main.py, which is actually Is `ــnameــ = main`?

**main.py**

```
import module_1


x = "45"
module_1.pp()

print(f"{__name__} : {x}")
```

**module_1.py**

```
def pp():
    import main
    main.x = 12
```

**Result :**

```
main : 12
__main__ : 45
```

Comment: yes, this is a well-known problem with Python. If other modules import your entrypoint module, it will be *re-imported* because the module system sees the entrypoing as `__main__`, so the caching doesn't work when it tries to load `main`. The best way to solve this is simply not to have anything import your entrypoint. You can just move the mutable state into it's own seperate module, imported by both `main` and others (frankly, having this sort of mutable global state is generally a bad practice to begin with, but that is how you could solve it in this case)

Comment: Also, your script *is* a module, it is available at `sys.modules['__main__']`, and you could access it that way too if you want a **very hacky** solution. Instead, you should go with using another module.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `dependency injection` pattern, not a specific library. I have a `config` module that's a class:

```py
class Config:
    somevar = None

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.somevar = val
```

Why the initial `somevar = None`? VS Code can easily see the variable; it's just for convenience.

After importing that class and instantiating an object, I then pass that object to the module that needs it.

*main*

```py
from config import Config
import module1

params = Config(42)
module1.pp(params)
```

*module1*

```py
import Config

def pp(params: Config):
    params.somvar = 39
```

There isn't a single "correct" solution, but that's the approach I take.